# extract android 1.6 calendar fields to vcal

Tags: java, database, android, sqlite, calendar

I want to extract android 1.6 calendar fields and put them into a vcalendar file
my problem is that i can't find some fields in the database like: DTSTAMP UID LAST-MODIFIED SEQUENCE

does anyone have a clue on how to find them?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google Calendar GData API to access the user's calendar data. The Calendar application is simply a cache of that data, and it is not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: that doesn't work with me,

my application should deal with the calendar database only ... it should not access the online google calendar